# Google Sheets, use return value of a formula inside another formula

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet with this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(may!B2:C)
```

It is accessing data from a sheet named `may`.
I want to make it dynamic, so when next month comes it would change automatically to:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(jun!B2:C)
```

I can get the actual month in a three letter format:

```
=LOWER(TEXT(TODAY(), "MMM"))
```

But how can I supply it to arrayformula? This does not work:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LOWER(TEXT(TODAY(), "MMM"))!B2:C)
```

Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `=indirect()`

```
=indirect(TEXT(TODAY(), "MMM")&"!B2:c")
```

[image]